# What kind of sounds would a creature from the void make?

Tags: creature-design, alternate-worlds, video-games

For a place I call *The Void*, its a place filled in darkness with no elements on the galactic periodic table, what sounds would it have? Especially the entities in the Void called VoidSpawn being multiple past lives fused into one entity like would they be screams of human/alien voices with different accents and tones? Having no physical forms and being energy based beings wanting to be whole again.

Comment: Is this science- or reality-based?

Comment: This seems like something that's more of an aesthetic choice than something specifically derived from the few facts of the critter you've described. How do you expect us to have a definitive answer to what sounds a creature without a physical form will make, when A. literally every sound ever made came from some physical form, and B. we have no idea what it even meant to exist without a physical form in your world.

Comment: Lacking conventional matter, sound is irrelevant. Sound is a wave transmitted through matter, and energy beings would use different methods of communication, perhaps mimicking soundwaves but in light waves,  radiation, etc.

Comment: Well, they do have parts of their bodies that are physical matter, just most of their body is energy, so they probably could morph the matter into vocal chords or something, but due to multiple consciousness-es in one body making multiple different sounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/multiple past lives fused into one entity/

**They would sing songs.**

Because they miss their bodies and want to be whole.  There are a bunch of them crammed in there, for some reason.  It is scary.  Some of them are (were) old ladies and they settle down faster than the rest.  One of them will get the idea to sing a settle-down song she knows.  It works and the spirits start to settle down.  The other old ladies in there figure out what that one is doing and so they come in with songs too.

The scared ones get less scared, and quit screaming and crying, and they want to contribute.  Some of them know some folk songs.  They have all different songs.

They don't all speak the same language so they don't all understand the lyrics.  But the songs sound good.  And there is nothing else to hear, or see in the void except each voidspawn, singing to itself, comforting itself.  You have to be physically touching one to hear it, of course.  It might appreciate it if you contribute a song.

Comment: Thanks man, I'll get my music team to work on that they are pretty talented so I hope they can do it, although it might be a while before they start it, as it's more for the end of the story

Comment: Also, since Earth had a mass extinction, killing about 99% of all life due to pollution, it would make sense as to why there could be so many of the VoidSpawn with many varying languages